# Could I Legally Fly a Paramotor as a Commuter Method

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, ultralight

I get permission from company security to fly into work using my paramotor (I don’t have one, but would like to get one).

We have six offices around the city. The city has two airports: one major international to the northwest of downtown and one smaller regional in the middle of downtown.

Would I be legally allowed to fly OVER the city (avoiding the downtown skyline) to make a direct route to my destination office for the day? What are regulations regarding paramotor flight in a metro area?

Comment: Paramotor as in powered parachute? Is the city covered by Class B or C or D airspace that would also require you to have a transponder/ADS-B Out and a radio? You can look at your area here https://www.skyvectors.com and see what the airspace is like.  I work at an airfield, and for a few weeks over the summer actually got a ride to where my airplane is kept and then flew to work. My car was in the shop, and it turned out to be less expensive paying for aviation fuel (and departure fees!) than renting a car for a few weeks.

Comment: Yes powered parachute, sry (I’d heard it also called paramotor). It’s covered in Class B airspace due to the Intl Airport to the northwest of downtown

Comment: this is a duplicate. Short answer is no, longer answer is in this question, which has an answer. [Could I use a powered parachute to fly around New York City?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45741/could-i-use-a-powered-parachute-to-fly-around-new-york-city)

Comment: Thx! I’ll check that out

Comment: @Jon: Check the floor of the class B airspace.  If it's several thousand feet above the surface, you MIGHT be able to legally fly under it.